# How to use firebase to send OTP to a mobile number SpringBoot?

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot

I am using Twilio to send OTP to the user's mobile number. Now, I am planning to migrate to Firebase as I am doing google and Facebook authentication using Firebase.

I could not find any documentation associated with Firebase with SpringBoot. Appreciate if anyone could point me to the right resources.

Comment: Have you found any workaround to do this?